# small picture contained inside a bigger picture function doesn't work

Tags: java

I tried to code the naive solution for that, which tries to match a first index and then go deeper.

But I get `true` when I shouldn't and I cant find why.

this is my code (Java):

```
boolean contains(BufferedImage img, BufferedImage subImg, int[] coordinates){
    boolean result = false;
    int verticalLimit = img.getWidth() - subImg.getWidth();
    int horizontalLimit =img.getHeight() - subImg.getHeight();

    for (int i = 0; i <= horizontalLimit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= verticalLimit; j++) {
            if(img.getRGB(j, i) == subImg.getRGB(0, 0)){
                result = true;
                coordinates[0] = j; // stores the first indices for self use
                coordinates[1] = i;
                for (int k = i; k < subImg.getHeight() && result; k++) {
                    for (int l = j; l < subImg.getWidth() && result; l++) {
                        if(img.getRGB(l, k) != subImg.getRGB(l, k)){
                            result = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(result) return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `if(result) return result;` should be `if(!result) return result;`?

Comment: @mangusta Realistically if I am reading this right he should just have a `return true;` at the end of the method, and a `return false;` where the current `result = false;` is and remove all the other boolean stuff.

Comment: @mangusta i would say starting with true "feels" unsafe. future fiddleing with the method may cause false positives.  also you check (0,0) on image twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your search for the sub image is off. you jump way far into the sub image by indexing with k,l i've changed to 0 and using k,l as offsets from i,j.  also use a labeled break from having to hold "found" state.  if all of the pixels match it reaches the end of the loop and returns true otherwise it breaks and tries again until all possible locations are tried and  returns false if none found.

```
static boolean contains(BufferedImage img, BufferedImage subImg, int[] coordinates) {
    int verticalLimit = img.getWidth() - subImg.getWidth();
    int horizontalLimit = img.getHeight() - subImg.getHeight();

    for (int i = 0; i <= horizontalLimit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= verticalLimit; j++) {
            subSearch:
            for (int k = 0; k < subImg.getHeight(); k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < subImg.getWidth(); l++) {
                    if (img.getRGB(l + j, k + i) != subImg.getRGB(l, k)) {
                        break subSearch;
                    }
                }
                if (k==subImg.getHeight()-1){
                    coordinates[0] = j;
                    coordinates[1] = i;
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: why did you put `return true` after `l`-loop only? both `k`-loop and `l`-loop must finish in order for the point `(i,j)` to qualify